# Plugging variables into HTML string programatically

Tags: angular

Does Angular come with any tools to accomplish this?

```
var html = `<div>{{name}}</div>`;
var data = {name: "wayne"};
????
var result = `<div>wayne</div>`;
```

Comment: Unfortunately, there's not enough information here to answer your question properly. What are you trying to accomplish _exactly_? What you are trying to do seems like very basic Angular functionality, but I think you're making it unnecessarily complicated. You may be able to solve your problem with a quick Googling for info about data binding in Angular. Or, if you want to dynamically add HTML to your component template at runtime, you can use the [Sanitizer](https://angular.io/api/core/Sanitizer).

Answer (score 0):

If you are asking about doing replacements like that? not really.

What Angular does is called binding:

You have a model, then you have your variables bound to that model, then, if the model changes, the values bound it change as well.

You can try almost any [AngularJS Tutorial](https://www.w3schools.com/angular/default.asp) to try this yourself.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this strictly with typescript and an `[innerHTML]`!

Your template would be `<div [innerHTML]="setName()"></div>`

In your typescript you would create a function that returns what you want inside:

```
data = { name: 'Wayne' }

setName: string () {
  return this.data.name;
}
```

Check out [this plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/xfAXuSYNlYnTVrMYGGGv?p=preview) for a demo on how it works.

Comment: Your answer is confusing. TypeScript is a superset of JavaScript. Also, the `[innerHTML]` feature is part of Angular, not TypeScript. There is no TypeScript in your HTML.

Comment: @Targaryen I added 'and innerHTML'. The answer includes a working plunker, so I'm not sure how that's confusing. It acheives exactly what was asked. It plugs data into an html string programmatically. I added the innerHTML to show how you would then display this in DOM.